# Forest tree - how to draw nodes with double border?

Tags: forest, trees

I'm looking for something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#/media/File:DFAexample.svg) (finite automat). I want to draw a specific node as endnode, that means this node should have two circles as border.
I'm using `forest` to draw my trees

Currently I'm having this code to generate a tree. There should be an "endnode" for "Jack", "Java", "Jim", "Ron" and "Ronny" (always at the last matching node)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        circle,
        black,
        draw,
        minimum size = 2em,
        font=\Large,
        edge={->},
        s sep = 30pt
    }
    [{}
        [J, edge label={node[midway, left]{J}}
            [a, edge label={node[midway, left]{a}}
                [c,  edge label={node[midway, left]{c}}
                    [k,  edge label={node[midway, left]{k}}]]
                [v,  edge label={node[midway, left]{v}}
                    [a,  edge label={node[midway, left]{a}}]]]
            [i,  edge label={node[midway, left]{i}}
                [m,  edge label={node[midway, left]{m}}]]]
        [R,  edge label={node[midway, right]{R}}
            [o,  edge label={node[midway, right]{o}}
                [n,  edge label={node[midway, right]{n}}
                    [n,  edge label={node[midway, right]{n}}
                        [y,  edge label={node[midway, right]{y}}]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please show us what you try so far!

Comment: @Zarko updated post

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but this is not a complete example. Please always post code we can copy-paste-compile. Is it just one node you want with `double` or several? If several, is there a pattern?

Comment: @cfr Sorry, updated my code. There are several nodes, but there's not a real pattern. The tree stores names and each endnode should be a double bordered node ('Ron', 'Ronny'...) Currently solving this by the answer provided by Zarko

Comment: @IanFako In that case you can add `where n children=0{double}{}` to the tree's preamble and all the terminal nodes will be double-bordered. You can then just add `double` to any additional nodes which need it in the tree. This is a bit more flexible if, say, you change your mind about how to designate the terminal nodes or something, and a bit less error-prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

meanwhile i found a simple example in my examples barn:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw=teal,
    line width=0.4pt,
    edge={draw=teal,very thin},
    grow=east,
    circle,
    l sep=19mm,
%    anchor=children,
    anchor=parent,  
  }
  [A, double, outer sep=0.5pt,
    [B]
    [C]
  ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

is this what you looking for?

Comment: ah yes, thank you, `double` is the option I was searching for

Answer (score 4):

Here's a less labour-intensive way of getting the pattern of edge labels you want. This is entirely off-topic and doesn't even attempt to answer the actual question, which Zarko has already covered.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    circle,
    black,
    draw,
    minimum size = 2em,
    font=\Large,
    edge={->},
    s sep = 30pt
  },
  delay={
    for nodewalk={fake=r,1,descendants}{
      if edge label={}{}{
        edge label/.wrap value={ node [midway, left] {#1} }
      }
    },
    for nodewalk={fake=r,l,descendants}{
      if edge label={}{}{
        edge label/.wrap value={ node [midway, right] {#1} }
      }
    }
  }
  [
    [J, edge label=J
      [a, edge label=a
        [c,  edge label=c
          [k,  edge label=k]]
        [v,  edge label=v
          [a,  edge label=a]]]
      [i,  edge label=i
        [m,  edge label=m]]]
    [R,  edge label=R
      [o,  edge label=o
        [n,  edge label=n
          [n,  edge label=n
            [y,  edge label=y]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: easier edge labelling]

This is a bit trickier, perhaps, than the usual case in which people want all the labels for left-hand branches to go one way and all for right-hand branches to go the other. The pattern therefore seemed technically more interesting, though not necessarily aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: a new example for mastering `forest` (+1). btw, in which time zone you live? here in gmt is time to slip :-)

Comment: @Zarko I'm horribly night-owl-ish ;).

Comment: ah, very the same as me ..., but now will go to slip :-)